# Have the single triggers higher priority on multitriggers with same conditions in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, multitrigger

I have a **TabControl** in my window. so i wrote a **style** for it like the following codes.

### In my codes there are to trigger (i used multitrigger after triger!):

- **First ---->>** A Trigger with **IsSelected=True** condition
- **Second >>** A multiTrigger with **IsSelected=True** condition

---

### My Tests:

I want use the second (multitrigger) with 2 condition (IsSelected=True + IsMouseOver=True), but i see it's effect will be show **just when i comment the single trigger**!!

So **i commented the IsMouseOver=True condition in multitrigger** and tested it again **BUT** the result was same as which was before **>>** the effect just show when single trigger is commented

Also **i placed Single trigger down and Multitrigger up** then tested it **BUT** the result was same as which was before **>>** the effect just show when single trigger is commented

---

### Now My Question:

- **Has my codes any mistake?**
- **Is in WPF the single Triggers have priority on multiTriggers with same conditions?**
- **The reason is different....**
- **How can i solve this problem?**

.

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl">
<Style.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">

                    <Border x:Name="TabItemBorder"...........
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush"........
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF999999"....
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF999999"....
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFa3a3a3"....
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite".....
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

**<-- First Single Trigger --> :**

```
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">

                            <Setter TargetName="TabItemBorder" Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush......
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9D6AC6".....
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9D6AC6".....
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA776CF".....
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
```

**<-- Second Multi Trigger --> :**

```
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                <!--<Condition SourceName="TabItemBorder" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>-->

                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                             To="#FFaD6AC6"....
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                            To="#FFaD6AC6"....
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                             To="#FFb776CF"....
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>

                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                To="#FF9D6AC6"....
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                To="#FF9D6AC6"....
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                To="#FFA776CF"....
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Style.Resources>
```

---

**EDIT:**

### **Notice:**

**Inside Trigger** i change the ***TabItemBorder*** background with this method:

```
<Setter TargetName="TabItemBorder" Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF9D6AC6" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF9D6AC6" Offset="0.584"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFA776CF" Offset="0.571"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

and **Inside MultiTrigger** i change the ***TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush*** background with this method:

```
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                             To="#FFaD6AC6" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                            To="#FFaD6AC6" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)"
                             To="#FFb776CF" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

and the ***TabControlBorderLinearGradientBrush*** is the *LinearGradientBrush* of ***TabItemBorder Background Property***

Comment: In which order are you defining these triggers>

Comment: @nit, same as my question (first i defined trigger and after it multitrigger). also i changed it's places and tesed but i cant see the effect. the effect will be show just when i comment the single trigger.

Comment: Does your <Condition SourceName="TabItemBorder" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/> trigger work when you comment out all other triggers?

Comment: No, and this is my problem :(

Comment: You are doing the same thing in both triggers right? Can you explain difference between those triggers?

Comment: ouu... when i add a foreground setter in multitrigger to change, it works! but the background effect inside the multitrigger just work when i comment the first single trigger.

Comment: @Mathew, I added a notice to the end of my question, can it help?

Comment: @nit, I added a notice to the end of my question, can it help?